# What all good audio versions of Shiv Tandav Stotram are available online?

Tags: practice, stotra, resource

The version sung by Shankar Mahadevan is currently the most popular one online. I remember hearing an old version previously but couldn't find it due to the search algorithm pushing newer versions. What other versions of this stotram are published/recorded digitally (by which artists), which are authentic and simple?

Also I noticed that few syllables in the stotram are altered from the written version, to fit the rhythm, so is that correct to do for daily practice? Would like to know other tips from people here who have experience in this for a long time.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMrG9t0sE1M ; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MZ2xZCX1BY ; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQhLNrUv9co ; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIhZSYq8nI0 ; https://open.spotify.com/track/6wzu0lhtLvtHqryPsXzLtv?si=429113c969494d61

Comment: This site isn't for questions like this though.

Comment: @Bingming I will keep that in mind, just wanted to get some suggestions from this amazing community.

Comment: You can ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism). Ask or answer a few other questions to earn at least 20 reputation, which will give you access to chat; consider taking the [tour].

Comment: Ah, alright. I have recommended you many song renditions of the stotram, one of them is not sung though.